# self-hosted solutions to get account balance

Tags: python, balances, rpc

What are the most common solutions self hosted solutions to get the balance of an account with a python script? I know that there are RPC nodes or are there other solutions? Maybe solutions that use database similar to what Dune offers but selfhosted ?

Answer (score 0):

The best self-hosted solution is to run your own RPC node. You can then connect to it over HTTP or websockets and retrieve whatever chain information you need. See https://ethereum.org/en/run-a-node/ for more info.